# Angular change property value of object array in html

Tags: angular

So I have an object like this:

```
class FileData {
    file: File;
    description: string;
}
```

In my components.ts I have an array of this object that contains an unknown amount.
My component.html looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of fileArray">
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(value)]="file.description" placeholder="Description">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(value)]="file.file.name" placeholder="File name">
    </td>
</tr>
```

My goal was that I can change the values of each property within the array with two way binding but this doesn't work.

Whats the right way to do this?

(Usecase: The Array contains X Elements. each one hase a file but no desciption. I want to fill the description or Change the file name)

Comment: I think you look for [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ngModel instead of value to bind values from an input:

```
[(ngModel)]="file.description"
[(ngModel)]="file.file.name"
```

Comment: Now it says `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`. Do I need to import something?

Comment: you need to import  `FormsModule` 

Comment: Ah of course, you have to enable the FormsModule. Into the imports add FormsModule.